# Router does not respond to changes in state. Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Router:
check auth before render

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requireAuth = to.meta.auth

  if (requireAuth && store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    next()
  } else if (requireAuth && !store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    next({name: 'login'})
  } else if (!requireAuth && store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    next({name: 'admin'})
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Vuex:

```
state() {
    return {
      isAuth: false,
      user: null,
      emailFormFactor: ''
    }
  },
 getters: {
    isAuthenticated(state) {
      return state.isAuth
    },
    getEmailFormFactor(state) {
      return state.emailFormFactor
    },
    getUser(state) {
      return state.user
    }
  }
```

App

```
onBeforeMount(
      () => {
        if (localStorage.getItem('auth-token')) {
          store.dispatch('auth/checkAuth')
        }
      }
    )
```

Before,i hve to check the validity of the token and after that, if there is a change of state.
Does it need to be tracked in the router?
Thanks

Comment: I think that a better solution is to use Axios interceptor - if the API returns 401 the interceptor can redirect to the Login page. Or, if you want a more abstract solution - it can emit an event on your global event bus, then you can subscribe to this event in the root Vue instance and e.g. show a non-dismissable modal dialog for logging-in so the user does not lose his/her context (as is the situation with redirecting to a separate Login page).

Comment: @IVOGELOV, About the interceptor. I tried to do it this way, the router didn't update anyway. Now I decided by adding an interceptor to the router itself, if the 401 status drops, then it makes a one-time call.